# Regex remove comma at the end of year and add parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove empty quote lines at the end of year:

```
2015,
```

to

```
(2015)
```

Here my code

```
(\d{4},)
```

But I don't know how to remove comma.

Comment: use "(\d{4})," regex

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d{4}),
```

Remove it from capture block, which is anything inside `()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
String replaced = "2015,".replaceFirst("(\\d{4}),", "($1)");
```

This will capture the number with the comma and put only the number in `()` (the captured group `$1`).

Answer (score 0):

There is always a different way :)

```
    String names = "2011,2012,2013";
    names = names.replaceAll(",", ")(");
    System.out.println("("+names+")");
```